# CKEDITOR:get last deleted element html value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I'm  working with CKEditor for the past few months.But, now I'm facing issue

for deletion in CKEditor.

**My Question is::**

How do I get the lastly deleted element's **HTML** value in CKEditor.

When I click the Delete button, I want to get what is the element will

be Deleted and get Deleted elements **HTML Value.**

Anyone, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can attach listener when editor content is ready, and check for delete or backspace press and get the last deleted content, an example could be like::

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'your-editor', {
    ...,
    on: {
        contentDom: function () { //editor content ready
            var myEditor = this;
            //add listener
            this.editable().attachListener( editor, 'key', function( evt ) {
                //if delete or backspace pressed
                if ( ( evt.data.keyCode in { 8: 1, 46: 1 } ) ) {
                    //get the last element
                    var lastElement = myEditor.elementPath().lastElement,
                        lastElementName = lastElement.getName(),
                        lastElementNode = lastElement.$; //native DOM object
                        //see what properties the node has
                        console.log(lastElementNode);
                        //you can use getAttribute to fetch specific attr
                        //for example, for img element's src attribute
                        console.log(lastElementNode.getAttribute("src"));

                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It Works like charm bro.But I want get image deletion details also.But it does't get those details when I delete the image.My image tag value is '<img data-selected="true" data-track-changes-ignore="true" id="cmd2" src="http://customer.onlinelic.in/Jaonline/images/Help.png" style="width:15px;height:15px;" title="Joe Bloggs:sd" />'

Comment: And then the **lastElementNode** value is null in everyTime.

Comment: @MariSelvan check this http://jsfiddle.net/0Lkvq69f/4/ . Its working fine.

Comment: Thanks, bro.But still, it doesn't get which is deleted in the editor text area.For example, i will delete the image it doesn't show the content of currently deleted image.It only shows the parent element.I want to capture currently deleted image html element.Thanks.

Comment: @MariSelvan for getting html of the deleted element try :: alert(lastElement.$.outerHTML);

Comment: Thanks, bro it works.But my content like this.'**<p><span contenteditable="false" data-selected="true" data-track-changes-ignore="true" name="cmd1"><img data-selected="true" data-track-changes-ignore="true" id="cmd1" src="http://customer.onlinelic.in/Jaonline/images/Help.png" style="width:15px;height:15px;"/><span class="CommentReference" contenteditable="false" name="cmtref1" style="display:none"><commentreference><comment><label></label><span class="CommentReference"></span></comment></commentreference></span></span></p>**
'  please Check this.Because when i insert like this it's not work.

Comment: @MariSelvan is that "contenteditable" property for "span" tag required. I think that might be causing the script to not work..

Comment: yes,@Sudhir it's important.Because it prevent when user type inside the image span.

Comment: Thank you for your Help **Sudhir**

Comment: Hi 'Sudhir' is there any way to get last deleted text in CKEDITOR.